# Is there an accurate way of counting interrupts from a GPIO pin on an i.MX6?

Tags: embedded-linux, interrupt, imx6

I have an i.MX6 on a custom board that has a fan plug.  Unfortunately however, the tach feedback line is attached to a GPIO pin.  Is there a way to accurately read the fan speed?  Some quick googling didn't reveal any edge counters or anything built into the i.MX6 that I could use.

I did try writing a proof of concept application that counted interrupts, but it is horribly inaccurate, and I expect it will get less so if there is load on the CPU.  I am seeing a fan running at a constant speed return values from 1500RPM to 8k RPM when the actual is 4k.

```
#include "os/threading/semaphore.h"
#include "os/threading/thread.h"

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

long timer_end(struct timespec start_time);
void select_gpio_number(const std::string &gpio_number);
void set_gpio_direction(const std::string &gpio_number, const std::string &direction);
void set_edge(const std::string &gpio_number);

static long period_ns = 0;

void select_gpio_number(const std::string &gpio_number)
{
    std::ofstream gpio_export("/sys/class/gpio/export");
    gpio_export << gpio_number;
    gpio_export.flush();
}

void set_gpio_direction(const std::string &gpio_number, const std::string &direction)
{
    std::ofstream gpio_direction("/sys/class/gpio/gpio" + gpio_number + "/direction");
    gpio_direction << direction;
    gpio_direction.flush();
}

void set_edge(const std::string &gpio_number)
{
    std::ofstream gpio_edge("/sys/class/gpio/gpio" + gpio_number + "/edge");
    gpio_edge << "both";
    gpio_edge.flush();
}

long timer_end(struct timespec start_time)
{
    struct timespec end_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end_time);
    long diffInNanos = end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec;
    return diffInNanos;
}

int main(int, char *[], char *[])
{
    int num_samples = 0;
    std::string input_number("39"); // GPIO2_IO7 -> (2 - 1) * 32 + 7 = 39
    struct timespec start_time;
    double frequency = 0.0;

    std::ostringstream input_value;
    input_value << "/sys/class/gpio/gpio" << input_number << "/value";
    select_gpio_number(input_number);
    set_gpio_direction(input_number, std::string("in"));
    set_edge(input_number);

    int tach_value_fd = open(input_value.str().c_str(), O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    struct pollfd tach_poll_fd;
    memset(static_cast<void *>(&tach_poll_fd), 0, sizeof tach_poll_fd);
    tach_poll_fd.fd = tach_value_fd;
    tach_poll_fd.events = POLLPRI;

    char current_tach_value;
    while (true)
    {
        // num_samples = 0;
        lseek(tach_value_fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        poll(&tach_poll_fd, 1, -1);
        read(tach_value_fd, &current_tach_value, sizeof current_tach_value);

        if (current_tach_value == '0')
        {
            // printf("edge detected\n");
            if (num_samples >= 1)
            {
                period_ns = timer_end(start_time);

                num_samples = 0;
                frequency = 1.0 / ((period_ns + 200000.0) / 1000000000.);
                printf("Fan is spinning at: %lf Hz or %ld RPM\n", frequency, static_cast<long>(frequency * 30));

                sleep(1);
            }
            else
            {
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start_time);
                num_samples++;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there something egregiously wrong with the code (yes, I know the functions should probably be static and that kind of thing) or a better thing to use (ideally built into the hardware)?  Or am I headed back to the electrical team and telling them to switch the pin?

Comment: Yes. Use `libgpiod` in event monitoring mode (i.e. configure the line to be an interrupt). In non-RT OSes it will be 99% reliable (there is still room when CPU is overloaded or stuck and you may loose IRQs). To get better guarantee you need to put some kind of external counter (there are such chips present) and get, let's say, each 10th event. Or even microcontroller that will simple answer you a result.